# Is there to make an html into a variable to search inside it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 html files, one named index.html another one called home.html.

I have a Javascript file and I want to get the div with tag "cont_expe_1" from home.html at the press of a button.

For example when I press the button to run

```
  document.getElementById("cont_expe_1").innerHTML='<a id="buton_exp1" class="buton_exp">Vedeti</a>';
```

but it gives this error every time I press it

> expe.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

I think it's because the code call the id inside document(I think document means the current html),is there a way I can get something like

```
var home=home.html;
document.getElementById("cont_expe_1").innerHTML='<a id="buton_exp1" class="buton_exp">Vedeti</a>';
```

I tried googling how to declare an html as variable and didn't really find anything.
Also tried to work around to get everything in one html, but it doesn't really work.

Comment: *with tag "cont_expe_1"* - Did you mean id?

Comment: You can fetch the other file and than parse it and search

Comment: `Get the div` ? in what way? Also `var home=home.html;` needs quotes, but the next statement does not use the var

Comment: yes sorry, it's an id

Comment: getElementById("cont_expe_1") it select id check your html page and check  the id there. error is showing because id is missing or maybe some spelling issue

Comment: `document` holds the dom of the currently loaded document. if `getElementById` didn't return an existing object, it means there's no such element you are looking for. Of course you can't fetch elements existing on a different html file... unless you explicitely load that file. But there's something sketchy in your question that surely hides a suspicious expectation

Comment: var home=home.html; I said this like an idea,I don't actually know if it works, I am loading home.html into a div inside index.html, when I press a button in home.html I want to change the id of an element <a> inside of index.html, outside of home.html

Comment: The spelling is correct, and that is the issue, I think it's not finding it because the button is inside home.html but "cont_expe_1" is inside index.html

Comment: I use innerHTML and <object type="text/html" data="home.html"> to load it inside the div.

Comment: Diego, I don't know why you say is suspicious. I change the id of elements to make "animations" with css and states. I know it's not really how you make it but I am trying to learn. For example
#button_activ{
  color= blue;
}
#button_inactiv
{
  color= red;
}
I use it on more complex stuff but to give you an idea

Comment: @Nisha of course they can

Comment: Thank you mplungjan for editing the question to actually be readable

Comment: @Sombra YW. Have a look at the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the html

```
const response = await fetch('./home.html')
const html = await response.text()
```

Then parse it:

```
const parser = new DOMParser()
const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
```

Then you can use the code

```
htmlDoc.getElementById("cont_expe_1").innerHTML='<a id="buton_exp1" class="buton_exp">Vedeti</a>'
```

Full example:

```
async function fun() {
  const response = await fetch('./home.html')
  const html = await response.text()
  
  const parser = new DOMParser()
  const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')

  htmlDoc.getElementById("cont_expe_1").innerHTML='<a id="buton_exp1" 
  class="buton_exp">Vedeti</a>'
}

fun()
```

Comment: Welp it doesn't give me an error,but doesn't change anything

Comment: @Sombra how do you check if it's changed?

Comment: I pressed the button and observed the div cont_expe_1, the button when pressed does the function fun()
Also put console.log('da'); at the start of fun() and console.log('nu'); at the end and both show in the console.
But the I dont see Vedeti in the div

Comment: Do you want to edit html in the other website?

Comment: no , I have a index.html and inside of one of the div I load with innerHTML('<object type="text/html" data="home.html"style="height: 100%;width: 100%;overflow: hidden;"></object>') home.html into the div. I have a button in home.html, when I press it I want to change an id of an element inside index.html. The reason I want an html as variable is explained above in the question, maybe there is an easier solution for something like this.